# Why do I get the HY000/2002 Error in xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

I've had this problem before: I download XAMPP and everything works fine, a week or so later I get the `(HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.` error. I cant find the exact problem other than that my computer is "actively refusing" the connection. My previous solution was to uninstall and reinstall XAMPP, it worked but was a pain in the butt to do. Now I get this error again and I want to stop it permanently! Any and all help would be VERY appreciated.

(I tagged php because it might have something to do with php, sorry if it doesn't)

Edit: I cant access the `localhost/phpmyadmin` and the server is not able to run

Comment: It could be related to corrupted MySQL log files. Go to mysql\data and try to remove (backup first!!!) the log files: ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1. Then restart.

Comment: PHP and MySQL, albeit bundled in a single package, are still separate programs. Is MySQL server up and running? Can you connect from other clients such as Workbench, HeidiSQL or good old command-line `mysql` utility?